# Google column chart hide annotation for data which has value zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

[image]

Below is my data and the series which I am sending to angular google wrapper : 
 https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

```
Data : [["Total",48,48,30,30,14,14]] 

Series : ["Event","Registered",{"role":"annotation"},"Participated",{"role":"annotation"},"Offered",{"role":"annotation"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

you will need to adjust the data accordingly

based on the `Series` definition...

```
Series: [
  "Event",
  "Registered",
  {"role":"annotation"},
  "Participated",
  {"role":"annotation"},
  "Offered",
  {"role":"annotation"}
]
```

a typical row may look like this...

```
Row: [
  "Test",  // Event
  40,      // Registered
  "40",    // Registered annotation
  30,      // Participated
  "30",    // Participated annotation
  0,       // Offered
  null     // Offered annotation
]
```

use `null` for the annotation when the column value is zero

Comment: The above Data that you have proposed have to be
    Data : [["Total",48,48,30,30,0],["A",null,null,null,null,null],  ["B",null,null,null,null,null]]

Comment: But I can't do that.

Comment: i'm suggesting `["A",0,null,0,null,0,null]`

Comment: Yes you are right but the list contains more than 100 arrays and they all are dynamic.

Comment: how is the array built? if this cannot be incorporated, you could use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) to replace the annotation columns with custom calc...